# Converting time in nc files

Tags: convert, netcdf, time

I have nc file where time unit is expressed as year and month in format "month as %Y%m.%f", type: character. For example, 199604.5 represents the year 1996, month 04. How to convert time in date format?

I tried next:

```
as.Date(ncin$dim$time$vals, "%Y%m.%f")
```

But I got the next error:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I also tried next:

```
as.Date(ncin$dim$time$vals)
```

but I got the wrong dates.

```
"2516-07-01" "2516-07-02" "2516-07-03" "2516-07-04" "2516-07-05" "2516-07-06"
```

Comment: What is the number after the dot (5 in your example)?

Comment: I don't know. Data are monthly.
            standard_name: time
            units: month as %Y%m.%f
            calendar: proleptic_gregorian
            axis: T

Comment: What do you get if you `print(ncin$dim$time$vals)` ?

Comment: [1] 199604.5 199605.5 199606.5 199607.5 199608.5 199609.5 199610.5 199611.5 199612.5 199701.5 199702.5 199703.5
 [13] 199704.5 199705.5 199706.5 199707.5 199708.5 199709.5 199710.5 199711.5 199712.5 199801.5 199802.5 199803.5

Comment: And `class(ncin$dim$time$vals)` ?

Comment: I get: "array".

Comment: Ahh ok, what do you get from `class(ncin$dim$time$vals[1])` then?

Comment: I get: "numeric"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a regular R user so I can't give the complete answer. Based on the comments to the question it seems that `ncin$dim$time$vals` is a numeric array containing values like

```
[1] 199604.5 199605.5 199606.5 199607.5 199608.5 199609.5 199610.5 199611.5 199612.5 
199701.5 199702.5 199703.5 [13] 199704.5 199705.5 199706.5 199707.5 199708.5 199709.5 
199710.5 199711.5 199712.5 199801.5 199802.5 199803.5
```

A single element in the array can be parsed to a date with this function

```
ymdouble2date <- function (d) {
  d <- floor(d)
  y <- floor(d / 100)
  m <- d - 100*y
  as.Date(ISOdate(y, m, 1))
}
```

So `ymdouble2date(199604.5)` gives a date `1996-04-01`. The above function ignores the fraction part but can be changed to give another day than the first day of the month.

The problem is that I don't think you can have an array of dates. So this

```
dates <- lapply(ncin$dim$time$vals, ymdouble2date)
```

gives a list of the dates. And if you try to get an array

```
d <- dim(ncin$dim$time$vals)
dates <- sapply(ncin$dim$time$vals, ymdouble2date)
dim(dates) <- d
```

then you get an array of numbers representing the dates as the number of days since 1970-01-01.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
time = var.get.nc(sst_nc,"time")
timedate = as.Date (time, origin = "2017-01-01")
```